# Local server for Firebase Hosting causing frequent HTTP errors in React app

Tags: node.js, firebase, http, create-react-app

A developer working in Cebu City, Philippines is receiving frequent networking errors using a common configuration between Firebase and [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development). We use `firebase serve` to start a local server for static assets in one terminal window. It starts up:

```
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: build
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
```

In a separate window, we run `yarn start` on a Create React App repo with a   `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",` entry in the `package.json` file. We frequently observe the following error:

`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /__/firebase/8.1.2/firebase-app.js from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000. See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT)`

with `ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END` exceptions killing the Create React App process.

Note: occasionally the error does not occur.

I can't replicate this problem in the US. With all of the software configurations I can think of being equal, I suspect there might be networking issues in the way as the firebase server does its [`Reserved URL`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) "magic".

Do you think I'm on the right track to suspect a networking problem? If so, can anyone assist with lower-level networking config that might alleviate the problem? (I'm thinking connection/timeout adjustments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you init your project from hosting URLs in `public/index.html` (like me), try to update URLs to the latest version (8.2.3), so all scripts would look like this:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/8.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

This is what worked for me. I hope so :)

Comment: That's all it took! Thanks.